# How to update a column value in multiple rows, in a single command, using Parameters in npgsql?

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

So what I'm trying to do is update a table of answers with new values when a user goes backs and edit/changes previous answers. So a questionnaire has like 20 questions that a user fills out and then get saved off in a Questionnaire_ResponseTable and if they go back and change their answers I want to update the table. Simple enough.

The tricky part is I want to protect against SQL injection so when I'm building my "stmnt" I'm inserting the user answers as parameters (in case they try to do something shady). The problem is since I'm trying to update say all 20 rows in a single database command I have ":answer" stated multiple times. What I have found is that npgsql treats all the ":answer" the same. So when I go to modify the 20rows in the database with each row corresponding to a question the user answered. Instead of getting 20 row with 20 unique answer every row ends up getting updated with the same answer.

I tried using string.format to do something like ":answer{0}",i to differentiate the ":answer"'s but that did work and threw an exception. I've gotten everything to work by not using parameters to insert the user provided answers so I know my posgresql command works the issue is just doing it in a safe manner to protect against injection.

```
public void UpdateAnswers(List<string> paramAnswers) {
        List<string> answers = paramAnswers;
        string stmnt = "UPDATE demographic_responses AS dr SET answer = c.answer FROM (values ";

        string updateVals = "";
        for (int i = 1; i <= answers.Count; i++) {
            updateVals = updateVals + string.Format("("+"'"+((App)Application.Current).participantDM.id+"',"+ "'"+i+"'," + ":answer{0}),",i);
        }
        updateVals = updateVals.Substring(0, updateVals.Length-1);

        stmnt = stmnt + updateVals + ") AS c(user_id, question_id, answer) WHERE c.question_id = dr.question_id AND c.user_id = dr.user_id";

        using (NpgsqlConnection conn = PgConnection.GetConnection()) {
            using (NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(stmnt, conn)) {
                for (int i = 0; i < answers.Count; i++) {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(PgHelpers.ToNpgsqlParameter(DemographicResponseTable.Column.answer));
                    cmd.Parameters[i].Value = answers[i];
                }
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting a parameter without actually sending it to the database (e.g. with ExecuteNonQuery), like you're doing in your code, does absolutely nothing; this isn't Npgsql-specific behavior, it's general database/ADO.NET behavior.

To help you understand, conceptually parameters aren't that different from inserting your value directly inside your SQL query (except, of course, for the injection protection and performance benefits).

If you're trying to optimize performance by not sending X queries to the database, consider changing your schema to have a single row with multiple answers, where responses to questions are represented as columns instead of rows.

Another option currently unsupported by Npgsql is to send multiple UPDATE SQL statements in one command, rather than doing ExecuteNonQuery for each one (the latter sends the SQL and waits for the responses). Unfortunately this is currently incompatible with parameters (but will be supported in the next major version of Npgsql).

Comment: I realize setting a parameter without sending it to the database doesn't do anything. I just figured you could build a stmnt that had multiple ":answer"'s in it and then you could somehow specify what would get plugged in for each ":answer". But I guess you can't do that they all just get treated like the same variable.



I ended up just looping and doing multiple ExecuteNonQuery(). The number of answer/questions is variable so that's why I don't want to change my schema to have rows that have a column for each answer.

Comment: Nope, :answer always maps to the same parameter instance, no matter how many times you specify it. However, as I said Npgsql v3 will have support for packing multiple SQL command into a single NpgsqlCommand (INSERT ...; INSERT ...; INSERT ...;), in which case you can have :answer1, :answer 2, :answer3, each mapped to a different parameters.